# Filename with dot in front

Tags: filenames

If there is a file and the filename starts with a dot, does that mean you created the file and you are hiding stuff in it, or can the files get created on their own without you creating the filename?

Comment: It means the file is hidden. Period. You may create such a file, or it can be generated by the system. There are many hidden files in your home folder storing your configurations. If you use `bash`, one important file among those is `.bashrc`.

Comment: WeijunZhou, "_It means the file is hidden. Period._" I'm afraid that's just wrong. The default position of `ls`, most GUI file managers, and shell globs is to ignore such files, but that is all. Nothing else differentiates or even cares.

Comment: @roaima That is pretty much one can say about file names. It's like asking about what `.txt` means in Windows. You may say that only some programs care about the `.txt` suffix and others don't, but that is the convention people use. There's nothing special at all in the file system for `.txt` files but I think no one will question the answer that `.txt means the file is a text file in general` if asked about.

Comment: @Olorin The main point of this question seems to be "what created the hidden file?".

Comment: @Kusalananda maybe, but that's not what's been asked.

Comment: I agree with leaving this one open separately, as 50% of the question is "can the files get created on their own without you creating the filename?"; the previous, linked questions are obviously good material to reference.

Answer (score 12):

The only thing "special" about a file or directory with a leading dot in its name, such as `.myfile`, is that it will not show up in the output of `ls` by default.  It will also not be matched by a file name globbing pattern that does not explicitly match filenames starting with a dot.

Assuming an initially empty directory:

```bsh
$ touch .myfile    # this creates an empty hidden file
$ ls               # this will output nothing
$ echo *           # this will echo a *
*
```

These files are usually called "hidden".  However, they are only hidden from `ls` and filename globbing patterns, and not hidden in the sense of "being a secret", or being malicious, or being undetectable or being unreadable by others (that depends on the file's permission and the permission of its parent folder(s)).

Anyone can create hidden files; it's just a matter of putting a dot at the start of the name.  The fact that a file is hidden says nothing about how it was created (explicitly by a user or by running some program).  For example, some applications create directories with hidden names (for storing configurations and cache files, etc.), and others create hidden files.

For example,

- The `bash` shell will often create `.bash_history` in your home directory, containing the commands that you have typed at the command prompt (so that you can easily recall them in a later session without having to retype them).  Upon starting up, the shell will also use `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` in your home directory.  If these files exist, they were likely copied to your account when it was created.
- If you use SSH, you will likely have a hidden directory called `.ssh` in your home directory.  This directory contains public and private SSH keys and may include some configuration files.  This directory should not be accessible by others.  It is unlikely that *you* created this directory manually.
- Many desktop utilities will store their configuration files somewhere under `.config` in your home directory and cache files under `.cache`.  Again, it is unlikely that you created these directories manually.

Configuration files in users' home directories (and elsewhere) are often hidden in this way so that they don't clutter the output of `ls`.

To view all files in a directory, including hidden files, use the `-a` or `-A` option with `ls` (using `-A` will not show the `.` and `..` names present in any Unix directory).

```bsh
$ ls -a
.       ..      .myfile
```

```bsh
$ ls -A
.myfile
```

In the `bash` shell, `*` and other shell globbing patterns will not match hidden names.  To get them to do that, enable the `dotglob` shell option with `shopt -s dotglob`.

```bsh
$ echo *
*
```

```bsh
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ echo *            # the * now matches a filename, so it is replaced by it
.myfile
```

Comment: Great answer from duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506366/259023