# Dot in front of file

Tags: filenames, dot-files

If there is a file and the filename starts with a dot in front of it. Does that mean that you created the file and you are hiding stuff in it or can the files get created on their own without you creating the filename. I'm just saying I have files with dots in front of them but I didnt create them.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange site! Please read over the [help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get more information on how to best post to this site. To get to your question, dotfiles or files starting with a dot character are hidden files. They can used for configuration files for applications you have installed or as profiles for your user settings. What files are you having an issue with? Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/506363/edit) your post to include more context. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not having a problem with mybfilea never looked at my files I'm getting accused of hiding things in files and also that I have hidden apps and I've never downloaded hidden apps

Comment: Don't worry and don't let people accuse you of doing covert operations on your file system. Everyone can type in `ls -alF` in a command shell, and all hiding goes away. BTW you might want to use `alias l='ls --color=tty -alF'` and with it just type one single `l` to see it all. Try `echo 'set nu' > .vimrc` and voila, you've line numbers in your `vi` or `vim` editor. That's all there is to it with "hidden" files.

Comment: -1 for intentionally asking duplicates.

Answer (score 15):

This can likely be explained by a [google post](https://plus.google.com/101960720994009339267/posts/R58WgWwN9jp) by Rob Pike about the origin of hidden files.

In the early days of Unix there was no concept of hidden files but the files `.` and `..` existed to represent the current directory and parent directory.  It became annoying to list these files every time `ls` was used so a simple change was made to the `ls` program to hide any file beginning with a `.`.  This change, had the unplanned effect of allowing for "hidden files".

As Rob Pike explains:

> As a consequence, more lazy programmers started dropping files into everyone's home directory. I don't have all that much stuff installed on the machine I'm using to type this, but my home directory has about a hundred dot files and I don't even know what most of them are or whether they're still needed. Every file name evaluation that goes through my home directory is slowed down by this accumulated sludge.

---

So to answer your question those hidden files you didn't create are likely some sort of config files from applications you have installed.

Comment: `... but my home directory has about a hundred dot files and I don't even know what most of them are or whether they're still needed` - Glad to know I am not the only one! There is a light at the end of the tunnel, there is movement to placing all user config files into [`.local`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) but not many applications follow this spec.

Comment: Heck, even on Windows (where those files are not automatically hidden and there's a defined and preferred place for such configuration to go into) I have currently 12 directories and 3 files beginning with a `.` in my profile directory. And I clean up those I don't recognize about once a month.

Comment: @crasic I guess you mean `$HOME/.config` which is for config files according to the freedesktop specification you linked. `$HOME/.local` is for "User specific data files". Actually quite a lot of applications are already using `$HOME/.config` by default or can be configured to use it, although it's still a long way till we can get rid of all the dotfiles in $HOME.

Comment: Btw. this seems to be a nice overview of software which adheres the XDG base directory specification or can be configured to adhere it: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_Base_Directory#Support

Comment: Unfortunately, the Google Plus link seems not to be valid now because of the G+ shutdown.